# Basic Syntax - why add properties

Tags: syntax, properties, neo4j

Sorry this is such a basic question, I think it might help me get a bettergrasp of the fundamentals....

In a basic query such as

```
(bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
```

why do we need to to include the property 'name'?

Why wouldn't the following work?

```
(bacon:Person )-[*]-(meg:Person)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without those properties you are just saying to Neo:

> Find me all the `Person` linked to another `Person`

`bacon` and `meg` will be just ignored from the DB because they are just variable names you set in the query for further filtering.

The former Cypher query (with the properties in curly brackets) can be seen as the equivalent of the following:

```
MATCH (bacon:Person)-[*]->(meg:Person)
WHERE bacon.name="Kevin Bacon" AND meg.name="Meg Ryan"
```